# The "Input Data:" on ethereum transaction, how to build it manually?

Tags: transactions

i need to pass parameter value of smart contract manually for flashbots transaction.

example transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0726bfbd4c162aa90867dfc8f94287410e51585fa9de8ea8c3dc7f5602a46420
claim contract : 0xb58a659Eee982Fe4E6Ce0c2C37EBD0F7E8224D7E
Method ID: 0x304c2c03 ( claim )
i see comment on parameter bytes32 r, bytes32 s : "Half of the ECDSA signature pair." . what is mean?

how to get value of bytes32[] proof, bytes32 r, bytes32 s ?
thank you very much for answering